# tomcat restart via JMX

Tags: tomcat, jmx

Is it possible to restart tomcat via JMX? Does tomcat has any mbean that supports restart of all its apps and services?

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know, there is no specific functionality to do this. However, you can install a custom MBean which will call :

```
public static final int RESTART_EXIT_CODE = -999;
....
java.lang.System.exit(RESTART_EXIT_CODE);
```

Then modify the command file that starts the Tomcat service to check the exit code of the JVM process, and if it is equal to the RESTART_EXIT_CODE, then re-invoke the command file.

Comment: You can't call System.exit() in your web app. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html#Background

Comment: Well, I just tried it. You can call System.exit(). However this can be disabled by the web server administrator.

Comment: Yep. Classic FAQ: Q: Can I call System.exit(i) in a <insert component here> ?   A: Yes, but only once......