# Restart tomcat through a java webapp running on it

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, web-applications, batch-file

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820438/restart-tomcat-through-webapp),and they said to use a batch script to restart a tomcat server using a webapp. The issue is that if you use Runtime.exec("batch.bat"), once you do the kill for the tomcat server, the server dies and the runtime dies.

I did a quick test of this by adding some prints to my batch file to be sure:

```
echo "lol" > file1.txt
net stop tomcatservice
echo "lol2" > file2.txt
net start tomcatservice
echo "lol3" > file3.txt
```

Only file1 was created as suspected.

Is there a way to do what I want? Is there a way for me to restart the tomcat server on a schedule through code in my webapp?

Comment: Try `Runtime.exec("cmd /c start batch.bat")`.

Comment: Try `call net stop tomcatservice` and `call net start tomcatservice`.

Comment: Karthikeyan, that worked, than you :)

Do you want to paste that below so I can mark as answer and give you credit? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Runtime.exec("cmd /c start batch.bat")` it starts a new process so it wont be terminated when the server stops.

Answer (score 1):

Create a batch file and write shutdown.bat followed by startup.bat. Call that batch file from your java code using Runtime. It should do the trick for you.